# How to return numpy array by reference in pybind11

Tags: python, pybind11

I am trying to return a numpy array using pybind11 from a C++ object, where the array is created from memory owned by the C++ class.  Right now, I have the class exposed by the buffer protocol and to return an py::array:

```
auto raw_image_cls =
  py::class_<RawImage>(m, "RawImage", py::buffer_protocol());
....
    .def_buffer([](RawImage &img) -> py::buffer_info {
    size_t buff_sz = 0;
    return py::buffer_info(
        img.ImageData(buff_sz), img.BytesPerPixel(),
        GetFormatDescriptor(img.BytesPerPixel()), 2,
        {img.Height(), img.Width()},
        {img.Width() * img.BytesPerPixel(), img.BytesPerPixel()}

    );
  })
.def_property_readonly(
      "img",
      [](RawImage &img) -> py::array {
        size_t buff_sz = 0;
        // py::capsule buffer_handle([]() {});
        py::capsule buffer_handle(img.ImageData(buff_sz),
                                  [](void *p) { free(p); });
        return py::array(
            py::buffer_info(
                img.ImageData(buff_sz), img.BytesPerPixel(),
                GetFormatDescriptor(img.BytesPerPixel()), 2,
                {img.Height(), img.Width()},
                {img.Width() * img.BytesPerPixel(), img.BytesPerPixel()}),
            buffer_handle);

      },
      py::return_value_policy::reference_internal)
.....
```

When I use numpy and do something like:

```
a = RawImage(filename)
b = numpy.array(a, copy=False)
a = 0
b
```

Everything works as expected, and b will remain.  If I do:

```
a = RawImage(filename)
b = a.img
a = 0
b
```

I get a segfault, which makes sense because a is destroyed, but how do I return a py::array and obtain the same behavior with numpy.array(a, copy=False) - which does not crash?

I have tried:

```
            return py::array(py::buffer_info(
            img.ImageData(buff_sz), img.BytesPerPixel(),
            GetFormatDescriptor(img.BytesPerPixel()), 2,
            {img.Height(), img.Width()},
            {img.Width() * img.BytesPerPixel(), img.BytesPerPixel()}));
```

without the buffer handle, but that just makes a full copy, which really slows things down.  Is there a way to tell py:array that we basically just want to return a reference or an object that points to my memory in C++ (from img.ImageData(sz)) to do the same thing as numpy.array(a, copy=False)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be not exactly the answer you are looking for.

The "problem" with a numpy array, as well with std::vector<> is, that it has the ownership. But in Python as well as in C++ the memory will be freed when the object is deleted.

I solved the problem by using a `std::vector<T> *` and constructing with it a `py::array_t<T>`:

```cpp
#include <pybind11/functional.h>
#include <pybind11/numpy.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

template <typename T>
py::array Vec2NpArray(std::vector<T> *data,
                      std::vector<size_t> shape) {

   // calculate stride of multidimensional data from shape
   std::vector<size_t> stride(shape.size(), 0);
   size_t elm_stride = sizeof(T);
   auto shape_it = shape.rbegin();
   auto stride_it = stride.rbegin();
   for (; stride_it != stride.rend(); stride_it++, shape_it++) {
      *stride_it = elm_stride;
      elm_stride *= *shape_it;
   }

   // tell python to delete pointer when deconstruction
   auto capsule = py::capsule(
       data, [](void *data) { delete reinterpret_cast<std::vector<T> *>(data); });

   return py::array_t<T>(shape, stride, data->data(), capsule);
}
```

If anyone has another solution, I would be very interested.